# Express GraphQL: I want to create a Team and populate with players, by passing the players IDs, but I can't find the correct syntax

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, express-graphql

Using Express-graphql, mongo/mongoose/ react.

Im Creating a database with Teams, Players, and Matches.

I want to write a mutation for creating a new team, which lists its players given their IDs, but I keep getting errors. I'm a newbie to GraphQL, so explain it accordingly please.

Can you help me populate "players" please?

### The Models

```js
const TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  teamName: { type: String },
  teamNumber: { type: Number },
  inMatchIDs: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Match" },
  players: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    wins: { type: Number },
    matchesPlayed: { type: Number },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

### The GraphQL Schema

```js
const TeamType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Team",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    teamName: { type: GraphQLString },
    teamNumber: { type: GraphQLInt },
    inMatchIDs: { type: new GraphQLList(MatchType) },
    players: {
      type: UserType,
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return parent.players.map((player) => {
          User.findById(player.id);
        });
      },
    },
  }),
});

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "User",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    wins: { type: GraphQLInt },
    matchesPlayed: { type: GraphQLInt },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
    token: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});
```

### The Mutation Schema

```js
 createTeam: {
      type: TeamType,
      args: {
        teamName: { type: GraphQLString },
        players: { type: GraphQLList(GraphQLID) },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        const team = new Team({
          teamName: args.teamName,
          players: args.players,
        });
        return team.save();
      },
    },
```

### ... and the Request / Response

```
//send request: 

mutation {
  createTeam(teamName: "champions", players: ["63382ba421b2cbfcd0531f4c", "63382ba421b2cbfcd0531f4c"]) {
    teamName
    id
    teamNumber
    players{
      name
    }
  }
}

//Response:

{
  "data": {
    "createTeam": {
      "teamName": "champions",
      "id": "63386d0a850a34f9823fd4cd",
      "teamNumber": null,
      "players": {
        "name": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Mongo:

[image: Mongo DB document]

Answer (score 0):

So after a whole day and a half trying to wrap my head around the relationships, here is how I solved it:

**The Mongoose model remains unchanged:**

```js
const TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  teamName: { type: String },
  teamNumber: { type: Number },
  inMatchIDs: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Match" },
  players: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
});
```

The TeamType in the Schema, is how the response displays the information and the subfields (see 'players' here) need to be resolved as this:

**The TeamType**

```js
const TeamType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Team",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    teamName: { type: GraphQLString },
    teamNumber: { type: GraphQLInt },
    inMatchIDs: { type: new GraphQLList(MatchType) },
    players: {
      type: GraphQLList(UserType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        let players = [];
        parent.players.map((id, i) => {
          players.push(User.findById(id));
        });

        return players;
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

But another important syntax to be careful of is the passing of the information in the args of the mutation:

**The Mutation**

```js
createTeam: {
      type: TeamType,
      args: {
        teamName: { type: GraphQLString },
        players: { type: GraphQLList(GraphQLID) }, //no need for [] as GraphQLList spells it out
      },
      players: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLList(GraphQLID)) }, // here I am defining that the value for the key 'players' will be a non-nullable list of GraphQLID type
      resolve(parent, args) {
        const team = new Team({
          teamName: args.teamName,
          players: args.players, // so that here, the model for "Team" understand that I am passing it Ids
        });

        return team.save();
      },
    },
```